# I would like python to do something when a color pops up on screen, how can i do that

Tags: python, python-3.x

What module would there be that allows my program to run IF it detects a certain color

for example, if I want my program to type red when #FF0000 pops up on the screen--how can i achieve that.  I know how to make python type, i know my conditional statements... i just need to know how to let python grab color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what you are looking for

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

while True:
    #gets current image
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    #checks which colour a specific spot of your screen has, by coordinates
    color = image.getpixel((660, 300))
    if color == (255, 0, 0):
        print("the color is red")
    else:
        print("its not red")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Pops up on the screen?  The entire screen?  A small snippet?  A single pixel?  It really depends.  A basic implementation could be screenshotting on some interval, and parsing each image pixel by pixel to detect the hex code you're looking for.

Comment: Good points, but this should be a comment, not an answer.